# Firebase cloud transaction triggers error

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a distributed counter via a Firestore transaction. I have a collection of Posts each with a subcollection of "count_shards". These each have three documents (1, 2, 3) that contain a "count" field.

When I create a "like" document for a post, I want to choose a random document and increment it by 1. I have the following Typescript code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addShard = functions.firestore
    .document(`likes/{docID}`)
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const postID: string = snap.data().postID;
        const randNum: number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1)); 
        const postRef = admin.firestore().doc(`post/${postID}/count_shards/${randNum}`);

        admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
            const postShard = (await transaction.get(postRef)).data();
            postShard.count += 1;
            return transaction.update(postRef, postShard);
        });

    });
```

I get the following error messages:

"ERROR: /Users//firecast/functions/src/index.ts[13, 9]: Promises must be handled appropriately"

"functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`"

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`runTransaction`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Firestore#runTransaction) returns a promise.  You need to `await` it.

```
    await admin.firestore().runTransaction(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `runTransaction` method returns a `Promise`.
And as the [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html) says: You have to return that `Promise`.

And these is important:

> ...if you want a function to stay alive during async work, you can do this by returning a promise from the function (except for HTTP/S triggers, which require a response sent to the client).

Or in other words: If you don't return that `Promise`, your function could finish without completing the `transaction`.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addShard = functions.firestore
    .document(`likes/{docID}`)
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const postID: string = snap.data().postID;
        const randNum: number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1)); 
        const postRef = admin.firestore().doc(`post/${postID}/count_shards/${randNum}`);

        return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
            const postShard = (await transaction.get(postRef)).data();
            postShard.count += 1;
            return transaction.update(postRef, postShard);
        });

    });
```